# How to fetch the sitemap.xml file which is created by strapi-plugin-sitemap on the frontend using NextJs by API?

Tags: strapi, sitemap, sitemap.xml

I have created the sitemap using strapi-plugin-sitemap in Strapi. Its working fine in the Strapi side but I need to get it on the frontend.

Here is the package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-sitemap

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It locates the sitemap at `/sitemap/index.xml` relative to the Strapi root.

Do you really need a sitemap for your backend? There is an official plugin for documentation that adds an OpenAPI specification that you can also parse in your frontend;
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@strapi/plugin-documentation